# HTML5 File Handeling in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

What techniques are used to load a file (ASCII or Binary) into a variable (var file = "text";) in JavaScript?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles (found by [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+read+file))

Comment: var file = $_FILES["filename"]; would be awesome.

Comment: Is the file to be loaded on the client or server side?

Comment: The file would be on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the new HTML5 way this is how I did it... keep in mind that I made a method called File() and this is not a true HTML5 method its a wrapper to it... this might be changed in the future so beware (maybe rename it).

HTML:

> ```
>   <html>
>     <body>
>       <input type="file" id="files" name="file"/> 
>       <button onclick="load()">Load File</button><br /><br />
>       <div id="content"></div>
>       <script>
>         function load() {
>           var fileObj = document.getElementById("files");
>           var fp = new File(fileObj);
>           fp.read(callback);
>         }
>         function callback(text) {
>           var content = document.getElementById("content");
>           content.innerHTML = text;
>         }
>       </script>
>     </body>
>   </html>
> ```

JavaScript:

```
function File(name) {
  this.name = document.getElementById(name) ? document.getElementById(name).files : name.files ? name.files : name;
}

// Reads the file from the browser 
File.prototype.read = function(callback) {
  var files = this.name;
  if (!files.length) {
    alert('Please select a file!?');
    return;
  }
  var file = files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
      callback(evt.target.result);
    }
  };
  var data = file.slice(0, file.size);
  reader.readAsBinaryString(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the new HTML5 File API and XMLHttpRequest 2.

You can listen to files being either selected via a file input or drag & dropped to the browser. Let's talk about the `input[type="file"]` way.

```
<input type="file">
```

Let's listen for files being selected.

```
var input; // let input be our file input
input.onchange = function (e) {
  var files = input.files || [];
  var file = files[0];
  if (file) {
    uploadFile(file);
  }
};
```

What you need to create a real multipart file upload request is a `FormData` object. This object is a representation of the body of your HTTP POST request.

```
var uploadFile = function (file) {
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('filename', file);

  // create a HTTP POST request      
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', './script.php', true);
  xhr.send(data);

  xhr.onloadend = function () {
    // code to be executed when the upload finishes
  };
};
```

You can also monitor the upload progress.

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
  var percentage = 100 * e.loaded / e.total;
};
```

Ask if you need any clarification.

Comment: I haven't tried all your code ... however, the new HTML5 way is really great... I tested it out and it works good...

Answer (score -1):

Have the JavaScript being generated inside a PHP or Rails (or whatever you use server-side) and include the file.

```
<?php
$my_string = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.txt');
?>

<script>
var my_js_file_string = "<?php echo $my_string; ?>";
...
document.write(my_js_file_string);
</script>
```

Comment: Or execute an ajax request for the file if the file is okay to be requested from client-side.

Comment: HTML5 has some new ways that maybe helpful.

Comment: If you are using the file in the HTML DOM its best to do everything in JavaScript.  If the file is updating MySQL I wrote some code in JavaScript to connect to a MySQL database.  I may soon be writing some some Java code to connect to MySQL so that the server doesn't need to be bogged down.